# TFS2015 Variables Issue (Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName)

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

From: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2264644

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables

Build.SourceBranch should map to $/teamproject/branch and Build.SourceBranchName should map to "branch" where the full path is $/teamproject/branch

I have a branch structure like $/MyProject/Development/MyBranch and when I try to use these variables in PowerShell (i.e. using BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH and BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME), I am getting:

BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH: $/MyProject
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME: MyProject

From my understanding of the article, the variables should return $/MyProject/Development/MyBranch and MyBranch respectively.

Anyone else able to repro this behaviour with a TFVC repository?  If you set up a vNext build definition with just a PowerShell task and add the following snippet, you'll be able to see the available variables in the output:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()
$environmentVars = get-childitem -path env:*
foreach($var in $environmentVars)
{
    $keyname = $var.Key
    $keyvalue = $var.Value

    Write-Output "${keyname}: $keyvalue"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to modify the answer as I have new find. After double checking the MSDN article, I found for TFVC BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH will be the **root server path for the workspace**. So I tried mapping the branch path to Server Path, please refer to the screenshot below. After specifying the Server Path to the branch path, you will get correct value of BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH.

[image]

Comment: I have two maps actually: $/Project/Development/Branch and $/Project/BuildProcessTemplates (this hosts project-wide scripts)... I'm going to guess that having these two mappings is what is making the variable act as it is.

Comment: I could reproduce your scenario. If you have multiple mappings, you'll only get $Project for BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH, if you only have one mapping, you'll get correct BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH as the MSDN article states.

Comment: Is this a bug or by design?  Ideally I'd like to be able to pull in project-wide scripts into my workspace from outside of any particular branch.. but if it comes at the cost of detecting the branch, I might have to push them into the branch and only use one mapping.

Comment: I can't tell it's a bug or by design, but I'll report this issue. As an  alternative, you need to push the scripts into the branch and only use one mapping as you mentioned.